# Asp Classic Write PDf and keep filename when printed

Tags: asp-classic, pdf-generation, filenames, content-type, response-headers

I'm trying to write a pdf file to the browser and when the client print the pdf the filename sent to the printer is the name of the file. But now i'm getting the name of the asp page sent to the browser "loadfile.asp"

Because I can't put a title in my page when i'm using `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"`, I've added a page that do a `server.Transfer`.

But everytime the code pass trought the `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"` the title get blanked.

So here's my code : 
First Page :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    <%= Request.QueryString("File") & ".PDF" %>
</title>
</head>
<body>

<%

Server.Transfer "loadfileAfter.asp"

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the Second Page (loadfileAfter.asp) :

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "Filename=" & Request.QueryString("File") & ".PDF"
    Const adTypeBinary = 1


    strFilePath = "D:\" &  Request.QueryString("File") & ".PDF" 'This is the path to the file on disk. 

    Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Open
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath

    Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read

    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing
```

I tought that this line would help :

```
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "Filename=" & Request.QueryString("File") & ".PDF"
```

But it did not change a thing.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this browser-specific? How is the PDF sent to the printer - is it sent by the browser, or by the plugin inside the browser (like Adobe Reader)

Comment: Yeah adobe reader ! sorry I've should have said it. and it don't seems to be browser specific

Comment: I don't think writing pdfs is something Classic ASP can do out of the box. ABCpdf is a popular third party component.  http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm

Comment: check this link: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/files/directories-fso/how-do-i-send-the-correct-filename-with-binarywrite.html

Comment: @GregM, I have same issue. did you find any solution for this case?

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:
`Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & fileName & """"`